# Moving more than one file with ftp OpenCF.FTP

Tags: c#, compact-framework, ftp

Can I move more than 1 file at the same time? Right now, I move one file, then if this is successful move another....with delegates and all. I was wondering if there was a simpler way to do this.

This lib lacks examples. I constantly find weird little things in my app that end up being hiccups; and I am not sure whether it is my code or the lib.

Like this issue - it makes logging into my app VERY VERY slow (40 seconds), just because I am getting 2 files upon login.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

FTP itself doesn't allow multiple file moves, so there's no way for any library to do more than one.  [See the RFC, section 4.1.3](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc959.html).

Comment: Thanks!
Makes sense. 

Addition question for you: how come this lib is very slow at logging user in? If I login to an FTP server through WIndows Command lilne (from any PC) it's super fast.

Same operation done with this lib takes about 20 seconds. is there any way to speed it up? why such a huge difference?

Comment: Actually it is 16 seconds - too long still. And then i need to ftp over 2 files, so it total these 3 operations take over 35 seconds.Too long for an average user. What are my options? As I mentioned, if i do these same operations through the command line, the response is instantaneous. Should I just live with the speed or???

Comment: If you step through the login code, do you see where the time is going?  It's pretty simple, synchronous socket comms, so it should be pretty easy to find.

Comment: I know I can step through the code. Since you wrote it, I thought that maybe you know some detail I am not aware of.

Comment: Bah, I wrote that years ago and has since cached almost all of the details back to my internal hard drive.  I have a hard time remembering how I architected things 3 months ago, let alone 4 or 5 years.  I'd go look, but I just don't have the bandwidth right now.